# Which way to use to access parameters in other Beans in JSF

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2

As far as I know, there are many ways to get attributes in other backing beans.

First is:

```
otherBean = (OtherBean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                                    .getELContext()
                                    .getELResolver()
                                    .getValue(FacesContext
                                              .getCurrentInstance()
                                              .getELContext(), null, "OtherBean");
String str=otherBean.someString;
```

---

And the second is to use session map:
(Set parameters to session map in other Bean)

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext()
            .getSessionMap()
            .put("someString",someString);
```

(And get the parameters in the current Bean)

```
String str= (String) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                                 .getExternalContext()
                                 .getSessionMap()
                                 .get("someString");
```

---

And the last is to use Annotation

```
 @ManagedProperty("#{otherBean}")
private OtherBean otherBean;
 String str=otherBean.someString;
```

---

So which one should I use? What's the differences between those methods? Or is the methods mentioned above wired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use always the last one because it is simply the most convenient. I would use `FacesContext` only if you can't inject the property or the bean using annotations. `FacesContext` is a singleton. Unit testing code using `FacesContext` is a pain.

I've never seen the first method (using the EL resolver) been used outside framework code.